# Is is possible to pass interface as constructor parameter in XAML, to make app more abstract?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I was thinking something like.

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="vm:MainViewModel">
        <ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
            <interfaces:INavigationDataProvider/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.ConstructorParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Can it be done this way somehow, or i need to set DataContext in code behinde in constructor (that im trying to avoid completly). 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `<interfaces:INavigationDataProvider/>` doesn't work because it is basically attempt to create an instance of interface (`new INavigationDataProvider()`) which is not allowed. Specify concrete implementation for parameter, e.g. : ``<models:ConcreteNavigationDataProvider/>``

Comment: Thanks for fast answer :) So maybe if i put it in some unityContainer and provide that class implementing that Interface, then could be done?

Comment: I'm sure you can use IoC container of your choice in wpf app. these posts can give some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25366291/how-to-handle-dependency-injection-in-a-wpf-mvvm-application; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802419/how-can-i-combine-mvvm-and-dependency-injection-in-a-wpf-app

Comment: Thanks, i'll check it up.